How to get line of code in app from stack trace?
I have a Xamarin.Forms project with support for iOS smart devices. In Organizer from Xcode we can download crash logs from our users (AppStore build). How can we pinpoint (native) functions in the stack trace to the Forms code in our app?
I tried to look for documentation about Xamarin from Microsoft. I expected a manual to pinpoint a function in a stack trace to code from the app. It actually resulted in a lack of documentation about this subject.

You'd need to symbolicate the logs.: Symbolicating iOS Crash Files. Also, you've posted this issue on Microsoft Q&A and has been answered, please confirm if it helps to solve it.
